# prevent my glasses from slipping down my nose

Tags: eyeglasses

Yes I saw others have had this problem and it seems like taking the glasses to an optician for adjustment is the best option. Well I learned a lesson, saved money and purchased online, so I don't have an optician to go to (prescription from an Opthamologist). I tried the hot water and bending option but it didn't work and I couldn't get them to bend to fit my ear better. I don't want an ugly attachment, so not sure what to do. Do I go to an optician and ask if I can pay for them to adjust, will they do that?

Comment: Can you describe what you did and what resulted when you tried the hot water fix? It might help us know more about the material used. Also, did you try simply bending it harder? My cheap glasses have a wire around the ear (inside) but not a low temperature thermoplastic.

Comment: One word: Optigrab.

Comment: Use a pair of pliers next time and they should bend easily. Be careful not to bend them too much or they will break!

Comment: Personally, I just get my glasses at costco which is the same price as the Internet but with the added benefit of free adjustments. You can ask your optician for a script which you can then carry into costco to buy the glasses there.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on country, specific optician's office etc, things may differ, of course. However, considering the ease of adjustment, they are quite likely to do it for free, especially if they do not happen to be very busy.

I know this because my mother had this experience several times - she has severe myopia, which progressed over time. She was nicely surprised every time, that she got the service for free.

Comment: I have walked in at opticians while on holidays with damaged glasses, screws fallen out or just in need of re-shaping and the opticians were always happy to help. But if in doubt, offer to pay before they accept job, so you know what to expect.

Comment: "offer to pay" I agree, that is the obvious thing to do. Never assume that someone is willing to work for free.

Answer (score 1):

As someone who's had glasses since the 6th grade, I know the problem well. I now have straight ear pieces and it's even worse. I've just lived with it, but I shouldn't. (Edit: I've since replaced my glasses with ones that have the standard curved ear pieces, and they stay on my face a lot better. I wish I'd done this sooner.)

> 1. Hair bands / hair ties
> 2. Oil free moisturizer
> 3. [Nerdwax](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00O0CK2UM)
> 4. Adjust temples with Polyolefin (shrink warp)
> 5. Bend the temples to fit

https://www.selectspecs.com/guides/how-to/stop-glasses-slipping/

You can also try a sports band for glasses, as I did during Army Basic and AIT. They can be ugly, wear out, and need washing, but they work.

There are also extra, small [silicone nose pads](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B078XR9K38) or large [nose pads](https://www.ebay.com/i/142828728431?chn=ps&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=711-117182-37290-0&mkcid=2&itemid=142828728431&targetid=595076158768&device=c&mktype=pla&googleloc=9030800&poi=&campaignid=1689407468&mkgroupid=74365777668&rlsatarget=pla-595076158768&abcId=1140476&merchantid=101510359&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIga3Tzq-F5AIVCdlkCh2MYAOfEAQYByABEgKQnPD_BwE) specific to prevent slipping as well as "[retainers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07B6K9SZQ)" that go on the ear pieces.

- **Disclaimer**: all links to products are just for ease of explanation and as examples. It's where I found the randomly found products to add to this answer, nothing more.